# Integral infinite series equality

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, power-series

Hello fellow friends of mathematics,

[image]

I found the following equation on a old Exam. Unfortunately there are no solutions available. If someone has an Idea, on how to solve this Integral-Series Equation I would really appreciate it.

Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for.

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Comment: Also, please don't post images of equations, it is against the policy of the site. Use Mathjax to format your expressions. Here is a quick guide: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions rather than posting images.  Images can't be browsed, and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  To begin with, surround all math expressions (including numbers,) with `$` signs.  Use `^` for exponents and `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1^{2/3}$` shows up as $x_1^{2/3}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
$$\frac{y^{1-3n}}{3n-1}=\int_y^\infty t^{-3n}\,dt$$
Hence when $y>1$
$$\int_y^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty t^{-3n}\,dt=\int_y^\infty\frac1{x^3-1}\,dx$$

Comment: Not my downvote but the explanation "Hence the RHS is" seems misleading.

Comment: Thank you for your Help!

Comment: This is not what I meant. "RHS" is misleading.

Answer (score 2):

We can get rid of the annoying infinite bound by a change of variable $x=t^{-1}$, and using Taylor

$$\int_y^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^3-1}=\int_0^{1/y}\frac{t\,dt}{1-t^3}=\int_0^{1/y}\sum_{n=1}^\infty t^{3n-2}\,dt.$$

Then integrating term-wise,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(y^{-1})^{3n-1}}{3n-1}.$$

Comment: Thank you @Yves!